# Let $\phi: G\rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. Is $Ker(\phi) =\phi^{-1}(e')$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi: G\rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. Is $Ker(\phi) =\phi^{-1}(e')$?

I say yes it is. But someone told me once that the inverse image is not necessarily in $G$ so I feel like there may be more to this question.

Comment: Your first guess is correct.

Comment: "inverse image is not necesarily in $G$". Write the definition of inverse image and read this again.

Comment: What is your definition of $\ker \phi$?

Comment: @Ihf I suppose $G\rightarrow G': \ker(\phi)=\{ x\in G| \phi(x)=e' \}$ The main problem I have is that I specifically recall my professor drawing two circles, one for $G$ and one for $G'$. Then he drew a square inside of $G'$ which was supposed to be an image, then he drew the preimage of that square and part of the preimage was outside of the circle $G$. This made me think that, in fact, an inverse image can be outside of the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

By definition the inverse image is in G.